# Generate Google Photo link from Google Picasa Web API data call

Tags: google-api, file-get-contents, picasa, google-photos

I am currently trying to generate a url to link to a public Google Photos gallery. I am aware from some research that all calls regarding Google Photos go through the Picasa API. So, by running file_get_contents on the following URL, I have retrieved a full listing of all public albums on my user account

```
http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/<USERNAME>?alt=json&kind=album&hl=en_US
```

This works perfectly and includes links to the gallery in Picasa. However, I would much prefer to be able to generate a link to the corresponding Google Photos gallery. On sharing Google photos, a shortened url is generated, like

```
https://goo.gl/photos/code
```

I was wondering if there was any possible way, given the album ID from the API call that such a link could be generated

Previous questions on this subject haven't generated much response unfortunately - is anyone aware of any such Google link generation capability?

Comment: It seems now that after Google's retirement of Picasa all generated Picasas links now automatically redirect to an equivalent Google Photos gallery so this is no longer an issue.